# Do you lose points for killing Wee People?

Tags: centipede

Do you lose points for killing wee people in the 1998 PC version of Centipede? If so how many points do you lose?

Comment: Have you played this game? I don't remember being able to kill the Wee folk.

Comment: @tugs Yes you can. They explode and say "Oh NO!".